# antd multiple select render issue

Tags: select, antd

I have a multiple select written in antd, when only select one option, it display `+ 1 ...`, instead of the actually value, when select multiple, it displays correct value. Any thoughts?

code:

```
options: {
  label: string;
  value: string;
}[] = [
  { label: '1', value: 'v1' },
   ...
];



 <Form.Item >
   <Select
     allowClear
     maxTagCount="responsive"
     mode="tags"
     options={assetClassOptions}
   />
</Form.Item>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

remove `maxTagCount="responsive"` fix the issue for me